# PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: mysql, pdf

I was wondering if it is possible to do a pdf like this using iTextSharp, and if so, how to.
I'm using MySQL databases to do it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPYDS.jpg

Have been trying to do something similar for 2 weeks.

Comment: *"Have been trying to do something similar for 2 weeks."* - what have you tried, what stopped you?

Comment: Been searching for examples, tutorials in the most various sites, and as a beginner, it became too messy for me.
Been trying to do it by myself, but it is too much.

Comment: It is possible to create a similar form as PDFwith iTextSharp. I don't see, though, what you need a database for in doing so. Other than that there essentially are some tables,  paragraphs, and lists, so look for examples focused on the iText classes `PdfPTable`, `Paragraph`, and `List`.

Comment: I'm doing it so it fills up the blank spaces with data automatically and then sends it to the user's email.

Comment: Have you tried to start by producing the static, empty form? As soon as you have that, you can extend that with fill-ins.

Comment: I did, and I got pretty much nothing, it became too messy for me.

Comment: You don't show any specific problem. So how can we help you? You should be aware that this is not a write-the-code-for-me platform, so what kind of answer do you expect?